# Cветофор дорожного движения с помощью многопоточности

Tags: c#, wpf

Задача представляет собой сделать светофор чтобы цвета красный, жёлтный, зелёный загорались постепеннно с каким то интервалом, при этом каждый цвет должен иметь отдельный поток.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Thread t1;
    Thread t2;
    Thread t3;
    Thread t4;
    Thread t5;

    Semaphore semaphore1 = new Semaphore(3, 3, "TestSemaphore");

    public delegate void delegate1();

    //(красный, жёлтый, зелёный, жёлтый, красный)

    void thread1()
    {
        if (!Dispatcher.CheckAccess())  // запущена ли эта функция не в основном потоке?
        {
            delegate1 delegate1 = new delegate1(thread1);
            Dispatcher.Invoke(delegate1);
        }
        else
        {
            Thread.Sleep(500);

            // Попытка занять слот семафора
            semaphore1.WaitOne();

            rectagle1.Fill = Brushes.Red;
            rectagle2.Fill = Brushes.White;
            rectagle3.Fill = Brushes.White;

            semaphore1.Release();

        }

    }


    void thread2()
    {
        if (!Dispatcher.CheckAccess())  // запущена ли эта функция не в основном потоке?
        {
            delegate1 delegate1 = new delegate1(thread2);
            Dispatcher.Invoke(delegate1);
        }
        else
        {
            Thread.Sleep(500);

            // Попытка занять слот семафора
            semaphore1.WaitOne();

            rectagle3.Fill = Brushes.White;
            rectagle2.Fill = Brushes.Yellow;
            rectagle1.Fill = Brushes.White;

            semaphore1.Release();
        }

    }

    void thread3()
    {
        if (!Dispatcher.CheckAccess())  // запущена ли эта функция не в основном потоке?
        {
            delegate1 delegate1 = new delegate1(thread3);
            Dispatcher.Invoke(delegate1);
        }
        else
        {
            //for (int i = 0; ; i++)
            //{
                Thread.Sleep(500);

                // Попытка занять слот семафора
                semaphore1.WaitOne();

                rectagle3.Fill = Brushes.Green;
                rectagle2.Fill = Brushes.White;
                rectagle1.Fill = Brushes.White;

                semaphore1.Release();
            //}
        }
    }


    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ThreadStart p1 = new ThreadStart(thread1);
        t1 = new Thread(p1);
        t1.IsBackground = true;
        t1.Start();

        p1 = new ThreadStart(thread2);
        t2 = new Thread(p1);
        t2.IsBackground = true;
        t2.Start();

        p1 = new ThreadStart(thread3);
        t3 = new Thread(p1);
        t3.IsBackground = true;
        t3.Start();

        p1 = new ThreadStart(thread2);
        t4 = new Thread(p1);
        t4.IsBackground = true;
        t4.Start();

        p1 = new ThreadStart(thread1);
        t5 = new Thread(p1);
        t5.IsBackground = true;
        t5.Start();
    }
}
```

Проблема в том, что программа выдаёт мне сразу последний цвет, т.е красный. В чём заключается ошибка и каково её решение?

Comment: Это учебное задание? Обязательно использовать именно `Thread` или просто светофор сделать?

Comment: @aepot Да, вся суть в этом задание и есть в использовании потоков

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Задание на самом деле простое, но с сюрпризами.

#### Обращаемся с UI правильно

Главная проблема, которая вам доставила бы больше всего проблем, это то, что вы когда зажигаете свет, вы в этом же методе гасите все остальные, а должно быть так - поток зажигает свой цвет, затем он же гасит, то есть вот такой код:

```cs
rectagle2.Fill = Brushes.Yellow;
Thread.Sleep(500);
rectagle2.Fill = null;
```

И для каждого такого цвета - свой поток. Я написал пример, но я для красоты использую там эллипсы, а метод для зажигания я запускаю с аргументами, передавая ему эллипс и цвет, поэтому у меня фрагмент этого кода мог бы выглядеть так:

```cs
ellipse.Fill = brush;
Thread.Sleep(delay);
ellipse.Fill = null;
```

Уже лучше, но здесь всплывает другая проблема - выполнение `Thread.Sleep` у вас происходит в UI потоке, ну потому что вы закидываете выполнение кода в `Dispatcher`. То есть у вас ВЕСЬ код светофора выполняется в UI потоке, а многопоточность вам только мешает. Давайте будем отправлять в диспетчер только рисование, а все остальное будем выполнять в потоках.

```cs
private void SetColor(Ellipse ellipse, Brush brush)
{
    if (!Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
        Dispatcher.Invoke(() => SetColor(ellipse, brush));
    else
    {
        try
        {
            ellipse.Fill = brush;
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException) { } // это проглотит исключение при попытке рисовать в уже закрытом окне
    }
}
```

А вызывающий этот метод код теперь уже по-настоящему выглядит вот так:

```cs
SetColor(ellipse, brush);
Thread.Sleep(delay);
SetColor(ellipse, null);
```

#### Синхронизируем светофор

Самое сложное - понять, как же на самом деле заставить светофор мигать в особом порядке, а не в разнобой. Случайные цвета сделать легко один вот такой семафор `new Semaphore(1, 1)`, добавить `WaitWone` перед каждым зажиганием и `Release` после - и готово.

```cs
semaphore.WaitOne();
SetColor(ellipse, brush);
Thread.Sleep(delay);
SetColor(ellipse, null);
semaphore.Release();
```

Если этот код правильно запустить в 3 потоках с правильными аргументами, светофор начнет мигать цветами, но вразнобой, никогда не угадаешь, какой свет зажжется следующим. :) Весело, но такая история для регулировки дорожного движения не очень подходит. Светофор должен работать по строгой программе и зажигать свои цвета по порядку, самым предсказуемым образом.

И решение - 3 экземпляра `Semaphore`. По одному для каждого цвета.

```cs
Semaphore semaphoreRed = new Semaphore(1, 1);
Semaphore semaphoreYellow = new Semaphore(1, 1);
Semaphore semaphoreGreen = new Semaphore(1, 1);
```

Но если использовать для каждого цвета свой семафор, они не будут синхронизированы, а просто будут гореть, так как им никто не будет мешать войти в свой семафор. Давайте заблокируем все семафоры

```cs
Semaphore semaphoreRed = new Semaphore(0, 1);
Semaphore semaphoreYellow = new Semaphore(0, 1);
Semaphore semaphoreGreen = new Semaphore(0, 1);
```

Запустим потоки, а потом разблокируем один

```cs
semaphoreRed.Release();
```

Загорелся красный, но он просто горит и дальше ничего. И уже очевидно, что красный должен когда закончит светиться разблокировать следующий семафор - желтый.

```cs
semaphoreRed.WaitOne();
SetColor(ellipse, brush);
Thread.Sleep(delay);
SetColor(ellipse, null);
semaphoreYellow.Release();
```

Красный разблокирет желтый, желтый разблокирет зеленый, зеленый разблокирет красный и так далее надо бы по кругу. А чтобы сделать по кругу, надо воткнуть этот код в бесконечный цикл.

```cs
while (true)
{
    semaphoreRed.WaitOne();
    SetColor(ellipse, brush);
    Thread.Sleep(delay);
    SetColor(ellipse, null);
    semaphoreYellow.Release();
}
```

#### Запуск потоков

Если запустить бесконечный цикл в `new Thread(...).Start()`, то приложение никогда не завершится, даже если вы закроете окно, потому что 3 потока продолжат бесконечно выполняться. Чтобы приложение смогло убить эти потоки для завершения, их надо объявить фоновыми.

```cs
Thread t = new Thread(RedLight) { IsBackground = true };
t.Start();
```

Вот и всё. **Задача решена.**

#### Пример

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="WPF Window" Height="400" Width="800" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Ellipse}">
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="60"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="60"/>
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
                <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Black"/>
                <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="1"/>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <Ellipse x:Name="RedEllipse"/>
            <Ellipse x:Name="YellowEllipse"/>
            <Ellipse x:Name="GreenEllipse"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Обратите внимание на регистрацию обработчика события `Window_Loaded` здесь, именно в нем я и запущу светофор. Вы можете точно так же запустить это все в `Button_Click`, разницы никакой, я не стал добавлять кнопку, чтобы не усложнять пример.

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
public partial class MainWindow
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void SetColor(Ellipse ellipse, Brush brush)
    {
        if (!Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
            Dispatcher.Invoke(() => SetColor(ellipse, brush));
        else
        {
            try
            {
                ellipse.Fill = brush;
            }
            catch(OperationCanceledException) { }
        }
    }

    private void RunLight(Ellipse ellipse, Brush brush, int delay, Semaphore current, Semaphore next)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            current.WaitOne();
            SetColor(ellipse, brush);
            Thread.Sleep(delay);
            SetColor(ellipse, null);
            next.Release();
        }
    }

    private void RunSemaphoreLight(Ellipse ellipse, Brush brush, int delay, Semaphore current, Semaphore next)
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(() => RunLight(ellipse, brush, delay, current, next)) { IsBackground = true };
        t.Start();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Semaphore semaphoreRed = new Semaphore(1, 1);
        Semaphore semaphoreYellow = new Semaphore(0, 1);
        Semaphore semaphoreGreen = new Semaphore(0, 1);
        RunSemaphoreLight(RedEllipse, Brushes.Red, 2000, semaphoreRed, semaphoreYellow);
        RunSemaphoreLight(YellowEllipse, Brushes.Yellow, 1000, semaphoreYellow, semaphoreGreen);
        RunSemaphoreLight(GreenEllipse, Brushes.Green, 2000, semaphoreGreen, semaphoreRed);
    }
}
```

Ну еще я оптимизировал код так, чтобы в нем не было методов с повторяющимся кодом.

[image: светофор]

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо, детально всё расписали понял суть, респект!