# Как реализовать синхронизацию потоков, работающих с общими данными?

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Пишу вопрос на данном сайте первый раз, поэтому могу немного некорректно выразить мысль.
Пишу программу для торговли на бирже.
Есть класс, в котором 3 события и список объектов `List<Robot> Robots`

```
private void ChangeInsPrice(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  lock(object)
  {
     foreach(Robot rb in Robots)
     {
     }
  }
}

private void AddOrder(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lock(object)
    {
       foreach(Robot rb in Robots)
       {
       }
    }
}

private void AddData(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   lock(object)
   {
     foreach(Robot rb in Robots)
     {
     }
   }
}
```

В событии `AddData` с сервера приходят данные каждую минуту. Мы проверяем некоторые условия и если что, указываем роботу войти в позицию, купить акцию.
Далее при изменении цены, вызывается событие `ChangeInsPrice` и, при некоторых условиях, мы указываем роботу выйти из позиции, продать акцию.
После каждой покупки\продажи вызывается событие `AddOrder`.
Я всё реализовал через `lock`, но понимаю, что после первого и третьего события, всем потокам необходимо ожидать того, чтобы вызвалось событие `AddOrder` и после этого уже продолжать свою работу.

А то проблема в том, что после выхода из позиции робота, я не успеваю получить сообщения с сервера в событии `AddOrder`, а вызывается другое уже событие. Получается, нужно не Lock, а что-то другое, которое скажет, что мы ожидаем, пока вызовется событие `AddOrder` и когда оно пройдет, мы продолжим работу.

P.s. Примерная блок схема на решение

1. Заходим в AddData
2. Остальные потоки ожидают если вызвалось событие ChangeInsPrice
3. Если мы покупаем\продаем, то встаем в ожидание вызова и обработки события AddOrder.
4. Продолжаем выполнение AddData.
5. После выполнение AddData, остальные потоки могут заходить в событие ChangeInsPrice.

Аналогично и с ChangeInsPrice.

Я так понимаю, что идеально для моего варианта подойдет `AutoResetEvent` где в событиях ChangeInsPrice и AddData после покупки я прописываю `WaitOne()`, и после в `AddOrder` я прописываю `Set()`

Comment: `что после первого и третьего события, всем потокам необходимо ожидать того, чтобы вызвалось событие AddOrder и после этого уже продолжать свою работу.` почему? Из вашего вопроса это вообще не очевидно.

Comment: Если у вас порядок возникновения событий играет роль, то скорее всего вы что то делаете не так.

Comment: И почему надо блокировать поток при событии? У вас роботы не могут быть вызваны откуда то ещё? Нельзя ли делать блокировку на уровне робота?

Comment: Просто у меня возник такой момент, что я указываю в одном событии роботу выйти из позиции, далее lock освобождается и мне необходимо ожидать события AddOrder, а в очереди потоков стоит другое уже событие. Но я не понимаю, как это исправить.

Comment: [Вот, потренироваться](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE%D0%B1_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85_%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B0%D1%85), [вот еще примерчик](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1242773/373567)

Comment: @tym32167 Просто мне необходимо обработать 1 случай. Вызывается событие ChangeInsPrice, мы выходим роботов и мы ожидаем AddOrder. Но в этот момент в очередь потоков входит событие AddData, а после уже в очередь событие AddOrder. И мне не нужно блокировать робота, мне необходимо подождать, пока обработается событие AddOrder и после уже проверять робота в AddData, даже если оно вызвалось первее.

Comment: Хоть это звучит и совершенно неправильно (зависеть от порядка событий), вы можете добиться того, чего вы просите, используя разные мониторы для разных обработчиков, то есть позволяя одним обработчикам блокировать другие обработчики.

Comment: @tym32167 просто это первое решение, которое пришло в голову, со временем возможно я выберу другой подход. А так да, я тоже только что об этом подумал, что нужно использовать монитор для контроля на разными участками кода. Спасибо большое за помощь.

Comment: Может ли быть такое, что в обработчике `AddData` будет сделано несколько покупок? В этом случае будет порожден один `AddOrder` или несколько? Если несколько, то нужно обработать их все до того, как продолжать обработку других событий из очереди?

Comment: Есть такой шаблон проектирования "конечный автомат", он же "машина состояний". Поизучайте, вдруг это похоже на то сто вам нужно.

Comment: @RomanKonoval Там всегда порождается один AddOrder.  Я дополнил свой вопрос, возможно станет лучше понятно, чего необходимо.

Comment: Хочу прояснить. Есть несколько роботов и несколько событий. Так вот: **каждый** из роботов должен реагировать на **каждое** событие? Или достаточно если **один** любой робот обработает событие?

Comment: Если я правильно понял, некоторые события являются более приоритетными и должны обрабатываться как можно скорее, а другие события могут подождать. Имхо, вам нужна очередь с приоритетами (или три очереди в данном случае). Закончив обработку какого-либо события, робот берёт из очереди самое приоритетное задание и выполняет. Когда нет самого приоритетного, берёт менее важное.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov каждое событие возникает независимо от роботов. И в каждом из данных событий мы проходимся по списку роботов, неважно, сколько их, один или несколько.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov вот, можете пожалуйста подсказать, где почитать про это. Я просто подписываюсь на события, но я так понимаю, очередь из потоков возникает автоматически и они сами по очереди обрабатывают события. А как можно контролировать эту условную очередь возникающих событий?