# Почему при повторных запусках программы результат всегда разный

Tags: c#

В этом коде создаeться несколько задач. И когда я запускаю их они выполняются рандомно. Не могу понять почему?

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Task[] tasks1 = new Task[3]
                {
                    new Task(() => Console.WriteLine("First Task")),
                    new Task(() => Console.WriteLine("Second Task")),
                    new Task(() => Console.WriteLine("Third Task"))
                };
                foreach (var t in tasks1)
                    t.Start();
    
                Task[] tasks2 = new Task[3];
                int j = 1;
                for (int i = 0; i < tasks2.Length; i++)
                    tasks2[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Console.WriteLine($"Task {j++}"));
    
                Console.WriteLine("Завершение метода Main");
    
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
```

Comment: А как должны по вашему они выполняться?

Comment: Упорядочено. Я посмотрел что есть метод Task.WaitAll который ждет завершения всех задач в массива а как упорядочить задачи в массиве?

Comment: Не запускайте их в тасках. Пишите просто код

Comment: Когда вы запускаете таски параллельно, без какой либо синхронизации, то эти таски могут начать или завершить работу в абсолютно любом порядке.

Comment: Для управления синхронизацией задач используйте примитивы синхронизации. [Пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1242773/373567). В показанном коде нет даже намека на то чтобы что-то выполнялось упорядоченно. К тому же 1) не используйте конструктор `new Task`, никогда. 2) используйте `Task.Run` вместо `Task.Factory.StartNew`, и да, есть большая разница. Предлагаю самостоятельно узнать, какая. :)

Comment: `Task.WaitAll` гарантирует упорядоченность результатов в массиве результатов, но к порядку запуска и завершения тасков это не относится. Например у вас есть `Task<int>[]`, вы его передаете в `Task.WaitAll`, так вот, `int[]`, который вернет `Task.WaitAll` будет содержать результаты выполняния тасков в том же порядке, в котором таски были в исходном массиве. Еще раз, это не имеет никакого отношения в порядку, в котором эти таски выполняются или завершаются.

Comment: Хотите, чтобы выполнение было последовательным - ждите завершения таски через `await`, прежде чем стартовать следующую. А главное непонятно - зачем тогда использовать асинхронный код, если вы хотите от него синхронного выполнения? )  Сначала сформулируйте - что вы вообще хотите то?

Comment: Возможно, проще будет сделать с помощью Parallel LINQ. Смотрите методы `AsParallel()` и `AsOrdered()`.