# С# Потоки. Mutex

Tags: c#, многопоточность, mutex

Первый поток генерирует случайным образом числа и записывает их в файл.

Второй поток ждет, когда первый закончит свою работу. Затем анализирует содержимое файла (который создал первый поток) и создает новый файл, в котором будут собраны простые числа.

Третий поток ожидает, когда закончит свою работу второй поток, и потом анализирует содержимое файла (который создал второй поток). Затем он создает новый файл, в котором будут собраны числа, заканчивающиеся на 7. При реализации должен использоваться **механизм мьютексов**

Проблема у меня в том, что у меня как-то непредсказуемо запускаются потоки (проще говоря, не в том порядке), а бывает, что все ОК (в общем, через раз). Хотя я запускаю необходимые команды mutex.WaitOne(); mutex.ReleaseMutex(); Что я делаю нет так?

Код прилагаю. Вспомогательный класс Worker, где происходит вся "магия"

```
public class Worker
{
    private string[] fileNames = { "Thread1.txt", "Thread2.txt", "Thread3.txt" };
    private Mutex mutex;
    Random random = new Random();
    //public static List<Report> reports { get; private set; }

    public Worker()
    {
        mutex = new Mutex();
    }

    public void Start(object numberOperation)
    {
        mutex.WaitOne();           
        WorkBegin(Thread.CurrentThread.Name + " начал свою работу");
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        switch ((int)numberOperation)
        {
            case 0: WorkBegin(Thread.CurrentThread.Name + " генерирует файл");
                    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileNames[0], false))
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
                        {
                            int number1 = random.Next(1000);
                            writer.WriteLine(number1.ToString());
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            case 1: WorkBegin(Thread.CurrentThread.Name + " ReadWritePrimeNumberToFile");
                    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileNames[1], false))
                    {
                        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileNames[0]))
                        {
                            string line;
                            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                            {
                                if (ulong.TryParse(line, out ulong number) & checkPrimeNumber(number))
                                {
                                    writer.WriteLine(number.ToString());
                                }                                              
                           }
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            case 2: WorkBegin(Thread.CurrentThread.Name + " ReadWritePrimeNumberToFile");
                    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileNames[2], false))
                    {
                        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileNames[1]))
                        {
                            string line;
                            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                            {
                                if (line[line.Length - 1] == '7')
                                {
                                    writer.WriteLine(line);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    break;
        }
        WorkEnd(Thread.CurrentThread.Name + " завершил свою работу");
        mutex.ReleaseMutex();
    }

    //Функция проверки является ли число простым
    private bool checkPrimeNumber(ulong number)
    {
        if (number < 2)
            return false;
        for (ulong i = 2; i < number; i++)
        {
            if (number % i == 0)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public event Action<string> WorkBegin;
    public event Action<string> WorkEnd;
}
```

Основной класс:

```
private string[] nameThread = { "Процесс заполнения файла числами", "Процесс перебора простых чисел", "Процесс перебора простых чисел по условию (7 на конце)" };
    public FormMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        buttonStart.Click += ButtonStart_Click;
        buttonReportShow.Click += ButtonReportShow_Click;
    }

    private void ButtonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        buttonStart.Enabled = false;
        Worker worker = new Worker();
        worker.WorkBegin += Worker_WorkBegin;
        worker.WorkEnd += Worker_WorkEnd;
        Thread[] threads = new Thread[nameThread.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < threads.Length; i++)
        {
            threads[i] = new Thread(worker.Start);
            threads[i].Name = nameThread[i];
            threads[i].Start(i);
        }  
    }
    private void Worker_WorkBegin(string info)
    {
        Action action = () => { listBoxLog.Items.Add(info); };
        this.InvokeEx(action);
    }
    private void Worker_WorkEnd(string info)
    {
        Action action = () => { listBoxLog.Items.Add(info); };
        this.InvokeEx(action);
    }
```

Класс ControlHelper

```
public static class ControlHelper
{
   public static void InvokeEx(this Control control, Action action)
   {
      if (control.InvokeRequired)
        control?.Invoke(action);
      else
        action();
   }
}
```

Comment: Это кто вас заставил мьютексами потоки синхронизировать? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1242773/373567 И не видно никакого смысла в многопоточке, если потоки выполняют работу последовательно. Для всего процесса достаточно здесь одного потока.

Comment: Я студент. ДЗ такой дали. Вот полный текст. Создайте приложение, использующее механизм мьютексов. Создайте в коде приложения несколько потоков. Первый поток генерирует набор случайных чисел и записывает их в файл. Второй поток ожидает, когда первый закончит своё исполнение, после чего анализирует содержимое файла и создаёт новый файл, в котором должны быть собраны только простые числа из первого файла. Третий поток ожидает, когда закончится второй поток, после чего создаёт новый файл, в котором должны быть собраны все простые числа из второго файла у которых последняя цифра равна 7.

Comment: Чтобы порядок был строгий, взятие мьютекса первым потоком должно произойти раньше, чем запуск второго. Например второй поток можно стартануть из первого после взятия мьютекса.

Answer (score 0):

В общем, переделал класс Worker. Вроде бы работает (раз 10 тестировал). Прошу проверить мой код. Буду признателен, если приложите свои варианты реализации исходя из условий задачи. Также хотелось бы получить рекомендации, где можно прочитать про мьютексы, семафоры и прочее. Метанит я читал. Вроде бы было все понятно. Но при решении задачи столкнулся со сложностями.

```
namespace Task4_5
{
    public class Worker
    {
        public struct Report
        {
            public int countNumber;
            public long sizeFile;
            public string fileСontent;
        }

        private static string[] fileNames = { "Thread1.txt", "Thread2.txt", "Thread3.txt" };
        Random random = new Random();
        private Mutex mutex1;
        private Mutex mutex2;
        private Mutex mutex3;

        public Worker()
        {
            mutex1 = new Mutex();
            mutex2 = new Mutex();
            mutex3 = new Mutex();
        }

        public void Start(object numberOperation)
        {
            switch ((int)numberOperation)
            {
                case 0: mutex1.WaitOne();
                        Work1();
                        mutex1.ReleaseMutex();
                        break;
                case 1: mutex2.WaitOne();
                        Work2();
                        mutex2.ReleaseMutex();
                        break;
                case 2: mutex3.WaitOne();
                        Work3();
                        mutex3.ReleaseMutex();
                        break;
            }
        }
        //Поток 1. Заполнение файла числами
        private void Work1()
        {
            WorkBegin(Thread.CurrentThread.Name + " начал свою работу");
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileNames[0], false))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
                {
                    int number1 = random.Next(1000);
                    writer.WriteLine(number1.ToString());
                }
            }    
            WorkEnd(Thread.CurrentThread.Name + " завершил свою работу");
        }
        //Поток 2. Перебор чисел для выявления простых чисел
        private void Work2()
        {
            mutex1.WaitOne();
            WorkBegin(Thread.CurrentThread.Name + " начал свою работу");
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileNames[1], false))
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileNames[0]))
                {
                    string line;
                    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        if (ulong.TryParse(line, out ulong number) & checkPrimeNumber(number))
                        {
                            writer.WriteLine(number.ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            WorkEnd(Thread.CurrentThread.Name + " завершил свою работу");
        }
        //Поток 3. Перебор простых чисел по условию (7 на конце)
        public void Work3()
        {
            mutex2.WaitOne();
            WorkBegin(Thread.CurrentThread.Name + " начал свою работу");
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileNames[2], false))
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileNames[1]))
                {
                    string line;
                    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        if (line[line.Length - 1] == '7')
                        {
                            writer.WriteLine(line);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            WorkEnd(Thread.CurrentThread.Name + " завершил свою работу");
            WorkEnd("Happy end");
        }

        //Функция проверки является ли число простым
        private bool checkPrimeNumber(ulong number)
        {
            if (number < 2)
                return false;
            for (ulong i = 2; i < number; i++)
            {
                if (number % i == 0)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

        public event Action<string> WorkBegin;
        public event Action<string> WorkEnd;
    }
}
```